# How do i make gnu as recognize all ARMV7 instructions?

Tags: arm, assembly

I disassembled an android library with IDA, and want to do some extra steps at the end of one of the functions. Currently, the last instruction bytes are `BD E8 F0 8F`, in thumb mode, which IDA disassembles to `POP.W {R4-R11,PC}`.

So i found a nice little piece of unused space, replaced the `POP.W` with a branch there, wrote my extension, remembered to put a `.thumb` and `.arch armv7a` at the start of my program, and finished my code with that `POP.W {R4-R11,PC}`. Unfortunately, using gnu as from an arm toolchain, this results in `Error: bad instruction pop.w '{R4-R11,PC}'`

Ok, gnu as doesn't like the .w suffix, so i replaced the instruction with `POP {R4-R11,PC}`. This changes the error message to Error: invalid register list to push/pop instruction -- `pop {R4-R11,PC}`

I know that some older ARM chips had restrictions on what you could do with registers from R8 on, so, just for verification, i replaced the instruction with `POP {R4-R7,PC}`. And indeed, as assembles this well.

Now I don't know how to continue?

- Maybe I have to give another architecture option to as. But .arch armv7a seems to be the newest which is valid with android armv7a libraries.
- Maybe i'm completely off track, and the pop instruction is actually a macro for two separate instructions, which pop high and low registers after another. But, the result of entering the individual two-byte instructions (`BD E8`, `F0 8F`) into the online disassembler seems to have nothing to do with popping from the stack.

I also tried disabling macros in IDA's processor options, which didn't change anything. So i'm inclined to think the byte sequence is a genuine 4 byte thumb mode opcode.

What else do i need to specify in my program to make gnu as recognize the instruction?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, `as`, uses the old 'divided' syntax for arm and thumb instructions. Hence it is not recognising your `pop.w` instruction.

To make it work, add `.syntax unified` at the start of your program.  This tells it to use the new unified syntax and you should find it assembles `pop.w` successfully.

See https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.24/as/ARM_002dInstruction_002dSet.html for more details.